# ¿Cómo hago la conexión entre Apache Netbeans 11.2 a MySQL (XAMPP)

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, mysqlconnector, netbeans-11.2

He visto tutoriales de como hacer la conexión a una base de datos MySQL pero usan versiones de Netbeans 8.0, 8.1... etc(Yo uso Apache Netbeans 11.2). En SERVICE cuando hago el test de conexión me dice que esta todo correcto, pero al escribir el código y correrlo me dice que hay un error, uso el método getMessage de la excepción y me dice que es en la parte "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", les dejo el código, o si saben una otra forma de hacerlo o si se hace distinto en Apache Netbeans

CODIGO CONEXIÓN:

```
package PaqueteBBDD;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conectar {
    Connection conectar=null;
    public Connection conexion(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conectar=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba", "root", "");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha conectado");
        } catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido conectar" +" "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return conectar;
    }  
}
```

CÓDIGO MAIN:

```
package PaqueteBBDD;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class NewMain { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conectar cc= new Conectar();
        Connection cn= cc.conexion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir la traza completa del error? De otro modo es imporsible saber que ocurre.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Errores de compilación no hay, el mensaje que da la excepción es "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: Lo que a mi me ha pasado es que te dice que el driver que mencionas está obsoleto y ahora tienes que usar este: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` intenta reemplazarlo o muestranos el log donde te salta el error/warning

Comment: En vez de `e.getMessage()` usa `e.printStackTrace()` para que te muestre en la consola la traza completa del error.

Comment: Hola @E.Betanzos y @FernandoOxyde, el problema ya lo he solucionado, la traza del problema era ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at PaqueteBBDD.Conectar.conexion(Conectar.java:20)
 at PaqueteBBDD.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:10)```

Comment: Añadiré una respuesta para que vean cual era la solución

Answer (score 1):

La solucion es agregar la dependencia mysql-connector al archivo de proyecto pom.xml, en mi caso era

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

hay que aclarar que esto es en maven y así se se pudo conectar, muchas gracias a los que se tomaron el tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: En realidad no importa que estes trabajando con Maven o no, problema es que no tenías en el classpath de la aplicación el driver para JDBC, y la forma de hacerlo con Maven es así.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione solo hay que agregar en JDBC DRIVER lo siguiente:

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```